# Retrieve Currency Symbol from a String

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, globalization

I am trying to retrieve an element from dropdown and storing in a `string`. I want to convert that `string` *currency symbol* to *currency code*. Following is the code i wrote:

I wrote below code but i am getting an error message :

> System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not
>   supported. Parameter name: name USD - United States dollar is an
>   invalid culture identifier.

```
public string RetreiveCurrencySymbolFromCode()
{
    string currencycode = " USD-United States Dollars";     
    string FinalCode = Currencycode1.Split('-')[0];      
    CultureInfo Symbol = new CultureInfo(FinalCode);
    return Symbol.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
}
```

I expect to retrieve USD and change it to symbol $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `"USD"` is name of a *currency* (`RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol`), when `"en-US"` is an (expected) name of a *culture* (`Culture.Name`). Let's obtain *all cultures* that use `USD` as a currency:

```
  string FinalCode = "USD";

  var result = CultureInfo
    .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
    .Where(culture => new RegionInfo(culture.LCID).ISOCurrencySymbol == FinalCode)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(culture => $"{culture.Name,10} : ({culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol}) : {culture.EnglishName}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 en-US : ($) : English (United States)
quz-EC : ($) : Quechua (Ecuador)
en-029 : ($) : English (Caribbean)
 es-EC : ($) : Spanish (Ecuador)
 es-SV : ($) : Spanish (El Salvador)
 es-PR : ($) : Spanish (Puerto Rico)
 es-US : ($) : Spanish (United States)
```

As you can see *several different* cultures can use the *same* currency. Technically, you code can be implemented as

```
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 ...

 string currencycode = " USD-United States Dollars";     

 ...

 // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217
 // ISO_4217 - all codes are 3 capital letters
 string FinalCode = Regex.Match(currencycode, "[A-Z]{3}").Value;

 var culture = CultureInfo
   .GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
   .Where(culture => new RegionInfo(culture.LCID).ISOCurrencySymbol == FinalCode)
   .FirstOrDefault();

 if (culture != null) 
   return culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
 else
   return "???"; // Unknown currency / culture
```

There are **2** issues here:

1. Currency code [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) is *three capital letter* combination (e.g. `USD`, `EUR`, `RUB`), a safier approach is to `Match` with a help of regular expressions
2. *Same* currency can be used by *several* cultures. You may want an additional rule to narrow down the required culture

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, regular expressions helped me resolved the issue. Thanks again for your help